# matlab loop for ssbmod "phase" and "frequency" specified with a set of numbers

Tags: matlab, loops

```
[x,Fs]=wavread('handle.wav')
Fc=[80 160 240]
phase=[3 1 5]


y = ssbmod(x,Fc,Fs,phase)
```

How can I create a loop where the variables of ssbmod is altered so that the first loop is defined as y=ssbmod(x,80,Fs,3) , then next loop is y=ssbmod(x,160,Fs,1), and the following y=ssbmod(x,240,Fs,5)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply loop through your `Fc` and `phase` arrays using a simple for loop

```
%// Pre-allocate cell array
y = cell(size(Fc));

%// Loop through all of your input parameters
for k = 1:numel(Fc)
    y{k} = ssbmod(x, Fc(k), Fs, phase(k));
end
```